# Given n-dimensional orthonormal basis with positive orientation, can I reach the standard basis via a sequence of rotations?

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Given a n-dimensional orthonormal basis in Euclidean space with positive orientation, can I reach the standard basis via a sequence of rotations?

Comment: sequence of rotations?

Comment: Some define a (proper) rotation matrix as an orthogonal matrix with positive determinant. With that definition of rotation it only takes one to reach the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The matrix going between these two bases is in the special orthogonal
group and is conjugate there to a matrix with block decomposition
$$\pmatrix{R_{t_1}&&&\\&R_{t_2}&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&R_{t_m}}$$
or
$$\pmatrix{R_{t_1}&&&&\\&R_{t_2}&&&\\&&\ddots&&\\&&&R_{t_m}\\&&&&1}$$
where $R_t$ is a rotation matrix in two dimensions.

Comment: the orthogonal group contains some reflections right? (assuming the basis is ordered)

Comment: Do you mind providing a rough proof or the intuition behind why this is true?  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnZheng It's eigenvalues and eigenvectors. They are complex in general but if you take the real and imaginary parts of a complex eigenvalue you get a 2-dimensional subspace where the matrix acts as a 2-dimensional rotation. You get an orthogonal decomposition into such subspaces (unless $n$ is odd where you get one-dimension left over).